# Ruby on Rails: 2.3.8: How do I get searchlogic to work with bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

Currently, I get this error: `NameError: undefined method`merge_joins' for class `Class'`

i'm just doing

```
gem "searchlogic"
```

and bundler says that it is using version `2.4.28`

So... what in the right searchlogic version to use with rails 2.3.8?

searchlogic 2.4.28 was the last version available before it started requiring 2.3.11 =\

```
NameError: undefined method `merge_joins' for class `Class'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:33:in `alias_method'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:33:in `alias_method_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.4.28/lib/searchlogic/active_record/consistency.rb:8:in `included'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.4.28/lib/searchlogic/active_record/consistency.rb:7:in `class_eval'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.4.28/lib/searchlogic/active_record/consistency.rb:7:in `included'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.4.28/lib/searchlogic.rb:34:in `include'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.4.28/lib/searchlogic.rb:34
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
~/category/app/config/environment.rb:16
```

on line 16 in my env, I do this:

```
Bundler.require(:default)
```

EDIT:
Gemfile:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
# system
gem "rails", "2.3.8"
gem "activesupport", "2.3.8", :require => "active_support"
gem "rake", "0.8.7"

# might be for POW, not sure
gem "childprocess", "0.2.2", :git => "git://github.com/jarib/childprocess.git"


# app
gem "mysql", "2.7"
gem "lockfile"
gem "ssl_requirement", "0.1.0"
gem "attr_encrypted", "1.1.2"
gem "searchlogic", "2.3.5"
gem "will_paginate", "2.3.14"

gem "garb", "0.7.6"
gem "delayed_job", "2.0.3"
gem "httparty", "0.5.2"


gem "pony", "1.1"
gem "friendly_id", "3.0.6"
gem "stringex", "1.1.0"
gem "i18n", "0.4.2"

gem "sms_fu", "1.1.1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the version(s) of searchlogic that I can use don't work with bundler, so I just kept this in my environment.rb:

```
config.gem "searchlogic", :version => "whatever"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 2.3.5 has decent Rails 2.3.x support:

```
gem "searchlogic", :version => "2.3.5"
```

Grepping through the history of the project shows the Rails 2.3.11 dependency was added in 2.4.29:

https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic/blob/v2.4.29/Gemfile

EDIT: Found some evidence on Heroku 2.3.5 will work with Rails 2.3.8, even though the dependency wasn't added until 2.4.28

Comment: so... then... why am I getting the error?, i'll add the stack trace

Comment: Sorry, 2.3.5 should work, convinced myself it might work in a later version do to the code searching.

Comment: so... I fixed the problem, by keeping config.gem "searchlogic" but the point of bundler is to get rid of that... any reason why I need that in order for my app to run?